# change the width of a group of elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing an HTML CSS JS code and I'm trying to change the style of a group of elements. I already know about document.getElementById(id).style.something = 'somevalue'; but it will require me to write about 25 of those and have 25 different ids. I wonder if there is a way to change the style properties in a class. for example:

CSS code:

```
div.text
{
width: 100px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="text">Some Text</div> <!-- and bunch of other divs like it !>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function changeWidth() {
document.getElementsByClass('text').width = '200px'; 
// I know getElementByClass doesn't exist I wanna know if there is something that would do that.
}
```

Comment: You have to add a style element at the top of the page that overrides all the other styles

Answer (score 3):

"document.getElementsByClass" might not exist but ["document.getElementsByClassName" does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

It's pretty well supported by all modern browsers [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getElementsByClass`, but there is `getElementsByClassName`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName